# What to do about an old unanswered question which you cannot verify the answer for anymore

Tags: discussion, old-questions

Over 1 year ago I did an internship in which I was presented with a problem which I asked here: [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data error when deploying application on production database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20211526/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-error-when-deploying-application-on/30768298)

During my internship I was never able to resolve the issue, and I am no longer able to test any of the given answers since the end of my internship. I do however still get notifications from people who try to answer this question, the problem is I cannot reward them even if their solution is the right one because I have no way of knowing if it is correct.

What should I do with the question? Should I accept the best answer? Should I leave it unanswered for ever and ever? Should I put an edit to the question stating I am not able to accept any answers because of the reason mentioned?

What is the proper thing to do?

Comment: The real answer is to use fusion logging.  Hope the answer you selected mentioned that.

Comment: If you decide not to accept an answer -- and maybe even if you do decide to accept an answer -- it might be worth adding a comment to the question indicating the current status (either as a comment or as a note in the body of the question -- at the top or at the bottom would be a judgement call).  You might even x-ref this question.

Answer (score 3):

The tooltip text for the accept checkmark suggests:

> Click to accept this answer because it solved your problem or was the
>   most helpful in finding your solution.

If the answer doesn't fit in one of those two categories, you should probably not accept it.  In this situation, it seems you cannot determine which (if any) are an actual solution.  I would not accept any answer under these circumstances unless I felt confident that a certain answer really would have solved the problem.  Otherwise, I feel I would be misleading people a bit claiming that I personally you found a solution that works or got me really close.

You and other community members are free to pass judgement on whether an answer is helpful by voting.  To me, an upvote says "I (anonymously) think this is a good solution or at least very helpful to know" while an accept says "I endorse this answer as my personal preferred solution."

Answer (score 1):

I would say that if can longer figure out a if an answer fixes the problem then you leave the question unanswered.  Just because your question doesn't have an accepted answer doesn't mean it won't help other people.  I would not just pick an answer and accept it as that tells people that it worked for you when obviously it didn't since you are here.

I would say leave it alone and let people keep adding to it.  Hopefully it will help out others as it did for some of the people who added answers.